# Get an example matched text from a regex pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there any way I can extract one example text that matches in a regex pattern?

For example:
Suppose that we have this regular expression pattern in JavaScript `/^No I do(n't| not)\.?$/`

There are multiple sentences which are valid in that:
"No I don't", "No I do not", "No I don't.", "No I do not."

Is there a code or method or function that suggests at least one of these? (Driven just from the regex pattern)

`/^No I do(n't| not)\.?$/` = = = > `["No I don't", "No I do not", "No I don't.", "No I do not."]` or just `"No I don't"`

Comment: https://github.com/alixaxel/genex.js